# php: write an array by clone

Tags: php, arrays

i got these arrays;

```
$arr1=array("1","2","3","4");
$arr2=array("a","b","c","d");

$x=array(1,3,4,2,4,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,1);
```

I want to print $x to the screen like this:

a,c,d,b,d,a,b,b,c,d,d,d,a

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question.

Comment: So what have your tried?

Comment: Seems pretty damn simple.. `foreach ($x as $k) { echo $arr2[$k-1].','; }`

Comment: http://php.net/foreach Good luck!

Comment: @sjagr: newp... 0-based arrays, remember...

Comment: @MarcB D'oh, I need more coffee.

Comment: @sjagr Also you get a trailing comma,

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol In all fairness I put in as much effort into my quick proof of concept that OP put into their question. I would pick your answer any day.

Comment: @sjagr Heh, fair point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could use a `foreach` loop like a primitive oaf (I'm kidding, don't hate me!), you could instead use functions that are designed for such things.

```
$map = array_combine($arr1,$arr2);
$result = array_map(function($i) use ($map) {return $map[$i];}, $x);
echo implode(",",$result);
```

Documentation: [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array-combine), [`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map), [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), [`implode`](http://php.net/implode).
As a general rule, using built-in functions will often be faster than iterating yourself.

Answer (score -4):

@Niet the Dark Absol Good answer

here is the one using foreach - using @sjagr suggested code

```
    $arr1=array("1","2","3","4");
    $arr2=array("a","b","c","d");

    $x=array(1,3,4,2,4,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,1);

    foreach ($x as $k) { echo $arr2[$k-1].','; }
```

Comment: Outputs `a,c,d,b,d,a,b,b,c,d,d,d,a,` - note trailing comma. This is why I said that `foreach` would be used by a primitive oaf ;)

Comment: Also, it's not nice to steal someone else's comment and make it an answer yourself. If you really want to do this, you should mark as Community Wiki so that you don't receive credit that isn't rightly yours.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes there is a trailing comma.. I am sorry but i was not trying to take credit for someone else answer.. that was not my intention.. if it was i wouldn't mention sjagr name..